# C++ assign element of a string to a new string

Tags: c++, string

Im trying to assign a piece of a string, to a new string variable. Now Im pretty new so longer, but easier to understand explanations are the best for me. Anyways, how Im trying to do it is like this:

```
string test = "384239572";
string u = test[4];
```

The full code of what im trying to do is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string test = "384239572";
string u = test[4];
int i = 0;
istringstream sin(u);
sin >> i;
cout << i << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Though it seems to complain at the upper part that I put up there. So how can I take a small part of a string from a string, and assign it to a new string? Thanks a lot in advance! If you know any good links or anything about this, that would be appreciated too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of the string [constructors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/)

```
string u(1,test[4]);
```

EDIT:  The 1 indicates the number of times to repeat the character test[4]

In your code you are trying to assign a `char` to a `string` object.

Comment: Okay, thanks, what does the 1 in this do though? Also can you maybe explain to me why my method doesn't work? That way I can have maximum understanding for future reference? :D

Comment: It's in the constructor documentation he linked: `string ( size_t n, char c );`
Content is initialized as a string formed by a repetition of character c, n times.

Comment: So when I use test[] it becomes a char and is no longer a string?

Comment: Also I noticed that when I do 
string u;
u = test[1];

It works, but if I try to do it in one line it won't. Why is that?

Comment: The string [assignment operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/) is overloaded to support assinging a char to a string.

Answer (score 4):

use substring,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string test = "384239572";
    string u = test.substr(4,1);
    cout << u << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `string` class has a method `substr()` that would be useful here:

```
// Substring consisting of 1 character starting at 0-based index 4
string u = test.substr(4, 1);
```

This generalizes nicely to substrings of any length.